# Make DT (DataTable) responsive using flexdashboard with Shiny in R

Tags: r, shiny, dt, flexdashboard

The following example (file `ex.Rmd`) results in a horizontal scrollbar when the window width is small. Any way to make the table fully responsive, i.e. remove the horizontal scroll and add the columns under the collapsed information?

````
    ---
    title: "Untitled"
    output: 
      flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
        orientation: rows
        vertical_layout: fill
    runtime: shiny
    editor_options: 
      chunk_output_type: console
    ---

    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    library(flexdashboard)
    library(DT)
    ```

    Menu
    =======================================================================

    Row
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------

    ### Testing  

    ```{r}
    renderDT(head(mtcars), extensions = c('Responsive'))
    ```
````

[image: Result of small window]

Comment: did you find a solution? i'm running into the exact same problem

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
renderDT({
  datatable(head(mtcars), extensions = c('Responsive'), 
            options = list(responsive = TRUE))
})
```

Comment: It seems to give the same result. I have added a screenshot of the output window.

Comment: this answer also didn't solve the same problem for me